# How can I disable scroll but also stay in the same scroll position

Tags: css, scroll

I'm trying to disable scroll for a popup to appear. I'm using the following code:

```
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

When I apply these styles, I go to the top of my page. I want to prevent scroll, but also stay in the same position. This is for a Sign Up popup. So, I want the users to be able to see what made them want to Sign Up in the background. **Any ideas?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: @noahnu I already checked that question. They don't care about the scroll position after scroll is disabled...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3nnua92/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `overflow: hidden;` on body, and simpliest way to make popup 100% on height and width is to give popup wrapper `position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 1000` Z index is for you to choose (so popup won't be overlaped by other container).

Answer (score 0):

Although the scroll is hidden, you can use  window.scrollTo() function to set the scroll wherever you need, something like

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

You can get the scroll position before opening the sing in dialogue this way.

> window.scrollTop
>
> window.scrollLeft

That could be the x and y you're looking for

Comment: How do you get the x and y coordinates? That way, I could create two variables `x` and `y` before the popup, then do `window.scrollTo(x, y)`